# How to check , if all my records are refreshed in a oracle table every friday

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that will get refreshed every Friday on a weekly basis, I need to place a check to make sure , the records that is available in the table is the latest refreshed records before we consume the data.

What is the best way to check using ORACLE SQL query.

Comment: Do you have some `update_date` column? This should drive your checks...

Comment: Yes  there is a date column , that will be refreshed every Friday to sysdate in the table.

Comment: ... so you need to check if all rows have the fresh date.

Comment: Yes Exactly , we will only proceed , if all the rows have the fresh date.

Answer (score 0):

The check query could be as follows

```
select min(update_date) from your_table
```

If the result is less that the last expected refresh date, you see that at least some rows were not updated.